# Converting Text Time to Numbers

Tags: database, view, time, sqlite

I am attempting to convert two time values, recorded as TEXT, to numerical values for use in a calculation to work out there difference, this is to be implemented within a View.

My current attempt is as follows.

```
CREATE VIEW TimeTakenSwimming AS 
SELECT UserDetails.username AS username, 
       SwimmingRecords.distance_in_miles AS distance, 
       SwimmingRecords.start_time AS starttime, 
       SwimmingRecords.end_time AS endtime, 
       sum((strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time)) AS timedifference,
FROM UserDetails INNER JOIN SwimmingRecords ON UserDetails.username = SwimmingRecords.username;
```

Now from this I am currently recieving an error relating to the "AS" Syntax. I have been through and corrected any spaces missing, added the missing brackets from the SUM calculation etc, however upon implementation i still recieve the as stated Syntax Error.

Located below is the code relating to my Schema to allow others to attempt to replicate the issue, I have utilised the SQLite manager Firefox Plugin for the implementation of this system.

```
CREATE TABLE "UserDetails" (
    "username" TEXT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE  CHECK (length(username)>0), 
    "password" TEXT NOT NULL  CHECK (length(password)>3), 
    "email_address" TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE CHECK (length(email_address)>3) , 
    "weight_in_pounds" REAL NOT NULL CHECK(weight_in_pounds>0) CHECK (length(weight_in_pounds)>0), 
    "height_in_inches" REAL NOT NULL CHECK(height_in_inches>0) CHECK (length(height_in_inches)>0), 
    "age" INTEGER CHECK(age>0), WITHOUT ROWID
    )

CREATE TABLE "SwimmingRecords" (
    "record_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE CHECK (record_ID>0) , 
    "distance_in_miles" REAL NOT NULL CHECK (distance_in_miles>0) , 
    "num_of_lengths" REAL NOT NULL CHECK(num_of_lengths>0), "username" TEXT NOT NULL , 
    "date" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, "notes" TEXT(50), 
    "start_time" TEXT, 
    "end_time" TEXT, 
    FOREIGN KEY(distance_in_miles) REFERENCES DistanceinMiles(distance_in_miles) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    FOREIGN KEY(num_of_lengths) REFERENCES NumberOfLengths(num_of_lengths) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES UserDetails(username)ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
```

I thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There too many opening parentheses after `sum`, and a wrong comma before `FROM`:

```
CREATE VIEW ...
SELECT ...,
       sum(strftime('%s', end_time) - strftime('%s', start_time)) AS timedifference
FROM ...;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was going to be something immensly simple that I was missing, again sincere thanks